# Tensorflow.contrib.learn не работатет

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я хочу написать классификатор фотографий на Питон используя tensorflow, когда я использую tensorflow.contrib.learn, компилятор Anaconda утверждает что файла _gru_ops.dll не сущетсвует и кидает NotFoundError... Переустнавливать модуль пробовал... Ниже скрины с подробными объяснениями:

Вот код программы и соответсвующее исключение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь переходим в папку, где находится якобы не существующий файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

похоже это [открытый баг в Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9481), который "взрывается" для не-ASCII путей.

В вашем случае это: `C:\...\Филипп\...`

Comment: А нельзя-ли как-то пофиксить это не изменяя имя папки пользователя?

Comment: @Philippe, можете попробовать "хакнуть" `load_library.py`, но я бы не советовал этого делать...

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь!